# iPhone not receiving some SMS messages (2FA codes and some URLs)

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

Recently, I realized my iPhone is not receiving some SMS messages. I have two SIMs in the phone (one physical and one eSIM) and the issue happens with both of them. I've noticed two types of messages are being dropped.

- 2nd factor authentication codes: "Your authentication code is 123456" and the like. This occurs for multiple different websites.
- Some URLs: eg `https://shotgun.live/events/bohemia-after-dark-gwladys-laplace-norn-margot-sergent` is one URL. If I send from another phone "test" "<the url>" "test", on my iPhone I receive only "test" "test". I am able to send the URL fine.

Resetting all settings on the phone does not fix it. Wiping the phone completely resolves the issue, but restoring from a backup (either a local backup on my computer, or iCloud) makes the issue return.

This is an iPhone 13 Pro running 16.5.1 (c).

Is there any feature that could be causing this, or is it just an iOS bug?

Update:

These appear to be two separate issues. AT&T support asked if I was having trouble with 2FA codes as soon as I said I was having an SMS issue, and they did something on their end to resolve that. It didn't do anything for the other messages.

Shortest message I've found that produces the issue is `shotgun.com`.

Comment: Are the sender numbers blocked?

Comment: That's apparently linked to something present in your backup. I would recommend reaching to Apple Support or visiting an Apple Store to better diagnose the issue first.

Comment: @nohillside The sender numbers are not blocked. (If they were, I wouldn’t be able to receive the “test” messages either.)